# Losing control while testing in Xamarin test cloud

Tags: xamarin-test-cloud

After entering into phonebook or gmail or playing YouTube through the testing application, I am losing all the controls to test or query. As soon as it comes into play I lose control. Then I have to manually deal with it. On writing tree on Repl mode I am not able to see anything.

Comment: So it is working locally but not in Test Cloud? Are you using the latest versions of the UITest packages or Calabash gems? Can you give us an example of the queries you're using that work in REPL but fail in your test project?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are leaving the application. Xamarin UITest works by running a client-side server next to or inside the mobile application. the client-side server is what enables us to interact with controls and query for things on the screen.

If you are on iOS, you have to have the Calabash agent installed in the application to make things work. Once you leave the application (switching to YouTube or other app), the client-side server is backgrounded and won't be able to do anything because of how iOS operating system is designed.

On Android, it depends on what version of Android you are using. Older Android versions don't sand box apps the same. Android 6.0 and above have more security controls and I wouldn't expect this behavior to work.

If you are trying to test if those things work, You should be testing that the Intent you are sending is correct. You are really testing the operating system at this point because you are verifying that YouTube or whatever did what you expected. Really we should have a base assumption that when we provide the phonebook with the proper intent, the operating system should behave accordingly. If you test that the video actually opens in the YouTube app, you are now testing if YouTube can open their links/intents successfully. Some people decide to test these things, many find that it is redundant and increases their teams cycle time.

I hope this helps!

Disclosure: I work at Xamarin/Microsoft